# HTML Purifier is adding encoding errors to UTF-8 documents

Tags: php, html, xml, character-encoding

I am using HTML Purifier to sanitize HTML/XML, but it's screwing up the character encoding which produces errors like this:

> Â
>
> Â
>
> On October 30, 1935, at Wright Air Field in Dayton, Ohio, the U.S.
>   Army Air Corps held a flight competition for airplane manufacturers
>   vying to build the militaryâ€™s next-generation long-range bomber. It
>   wasnâ€™t supposed to be much of a competition. In early evaluations,
>   the Boeing Corporationâ€™s gleaming aluminum-alloy Model 299 had
>   trounced the designs of Martin and Douglas.

Based on HTML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>The Checklist Manifesto: How to Get Things Right</title>
    <meta content="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/><link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/><style type="text/css">
```

...

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('Attr.EnableID', true);
$config->set('HTML.TidyLevel', 'heavy');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$cleanHTML = $purifier->purify($htmlFile);
```

The code is sanitized perfectly when I use PHP's Tidy extension, so I don't really understand what's causing the problem. I could really use some help.

Comment: It looks like you took a UTF8 document and fed it into an 8859-to-UTF8 translator, so now your UTF8 3-byte "fancy apostrophes" are munged into 8-byte sequences of gibberish.

Comment: @Sammitch The $htmlFile variable is a string containing the unadulterated source code from an HTML. HTML Purifier is the only function that could be altering the HTML.